# Easy way to get Drupal Header and Footer?

Tags: drupal, templates

The title is probably not the best description. I want two functions:

```
getHeader();
getFooter();
```

The header must return all the content in the template.php file BEFORE

```
print $content;
```

And the latter must return everything after it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible, but you'll need to custom code it, and it'll potentially get complicated with some themes.

Comment: I have WHMCS installed, and it has a HEADER.tpl and FOOTER.tpl files. And I want to place the content in there. Instead of hardcoding it, i want it to be taken from whmcs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to get the all except `$content` and wrap your display in it, why don't you just take your content and theme it (put it into `$content`). That will be a lot easier, Drupal was meant for this.

Comment: I'll need to find a hook that returns the content for WHMCS. This might not be a bad idea. :-)

Comment: Ah. This will bring in quite a few problems. The links that WHMCS generates, won't work if the content was pulled into Drupal. I will definitely need a getHeader and getFooter command.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal makes use of "regions".  What you can do is give your site three regions (header, content, footer).

Regions are defined in the theme's .info file in the form "region[backend_name] = Title that shows up in frontend". Having the regions "header", "content", and "footer" could be defined thus:

```
region[header] = This is the Header
region[content] = This is the Content
region[footer] = This is the Footer
```

After defining the regions in the .info file and enabling the theme, each region can be printed using the backend name thus:

```
print $header;
print $content;
print $footer;
```

Blocks are assigned to a region at /admin/build/block

Comment: I need the inverse of this. I.e. Give me the rendered page, excluding such and such block.

Comment: Are you doing this from inside drupal or parsing the rendered page externally?